# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position 96

Tags: javascript, java, json, servlets

I am creating a web app that allows users to login and I have some sample login username/passwords in my database. I have a login.js file that handled the login to send to the Java servlet and was working fine until I tried to login on the AWS server. Now I cannot even get it to work on my localhost. I never changed any of the login code from when it was working to not working.

```
 /**
 * Handle the data returned by LoginServlet
 * @param resultDataString jsonObject
 */
function handleLoginResult(resultDataString) {
    resultDataJson = JSON.parse(resultDataString); //getting error here

    // If login success, redirect to index.html page
    if (resultDataJson["status"] === "success") {
        window.location.replace("index.html");
    }
    // If login fail, display error message on <div> with id "login_error_message"
    else {

        jQuery("#login_error_message").text(resultDataJson["message"]);
    }
}

/**
 * Submit the form content with POST method
 * @param formSubmitEvent
 */
function submitLoginForm(formSubmitEvent) {

    formSubmitEvent.preventDefault();

    jQuery.post(
        "login",
        jQuery("#login_form").serialize(),
        (resultDataString) => handleLoginResult(resultDataString)); //getting error here

}

// Bind the submit action of the form to a handler function
jQuery("#login_form").submit((event) => submitLoginForm(event));
```

Comment: Sounds like the format of the data changed or is corrupt now.  Check the code on server and the data sent from it

Comment: sorry what do you mean by check the server exactly? this is my first web app

Comment: You haven't included any Java / servlet code, and you haven't shown us the JSON that is causing the error.   Print out what is in `resultDataString`

Comment: Show us the json that you get back from the server.

Comment: `console.log(resultDataString)` results in `{"status":"fail","message":null}`

Comment: `resultDataJson = JSON.parse(resultDataString); //getting error here` I am fairly sure it's because `resultDataString` is not actually a string. Yes, you are *supposed* to get JSON (which is a string type) but jQuery usually parses that for you, so you don't have to do `JSON.parse` on it.